# Android context NullPointerException : Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: android, kotlin, android-context

I want to create TableLayout in my fragment to insert data.
I used for that this methode below.

I have to call the methode **updateTable** outside of the onCreated view method.

But I got always this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

The complete code of the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.tharwa.tdm2_exo2, PID: 5480
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
                      at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:364)

                      ...

                      at com.tharwa.tdm2_exo2.TableAgent.TablePresentation.updateTable(TablePresentation.kt:61)
```

I have tried several ways to avoid this error but still always appear. I tried to get the context from `onCreatedView` too but does not work.

Here is my function:

```
class TablePresentation : DialogFragment(),tableContract.View
{
    ....

     override fun updateTable(temps: ArrayList<Double>)
     {
         for (i in 0 until temps.size) {
        val row =  TableRow(activity)
        row.setLayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
        row.setWeightSum(2.0f)
        val tv1 = TextView(activity)
        val tv2= TextView(activity)

        ...

        table!!.addView(row, i)
        }
     }

}
```

Here is the complete code of the class:

```
class TablePresentation : DialogFragment(),tableContract.View
{

    var table: TableLayout?=null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, parent: ViewGroup?, state: Bundle?): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, state)
        val view = activity.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.table_fragment, parent, false)
        view.findViewById<View>(R.id.button_close)?.setOnClickListener({ dismiss() })
        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        table = view?.findViewById<View>(R.id.simpleTableLayout) as TableLayout
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     ...
    }

    override fun onStart() {
      ...
    }


     override fun updateTable(temps: ArrayList<Double>)
     {
        ....
     }

}
```

and here is how I attach the view to the controller:

```
class PaletteController
{
    var father: FatherController?=null
    val view: PaletterPresentation
    var model:PaletteAbstraction?=null
    var TableSon:TableController?=null

    constructor(view:PaletterPresentation)
    {
        this.view=view
        view.controller=this
        this.model= PaletteAbstraction()

    }
    ....

    fun notifyTableChild()
    {
        TableSon= TableController(view.getTableChild())
        setChildSFather()
        TableSon?.updateTable( father!!.giveTemps())
    }
}
```

Here is why I create the fragment:

```
class PaletterPresentation: Fragment(), PaletteContract.View
{
    var views: View? = null
    var controller: PaletteController?=null

    val tablePresentation=TablePresentation()

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        views = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.palette_fragement, container, false)
        return views
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            val ft = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            tablePresentation.show(ft, ContentValues.TAG)
            controller?.notifyTableChild()
        }
    }


    override fun getTableChild(): TablePresentation {
        return tablePresentation
    }

}
```

I really do not  know how to fix this problem.

Comment: Wheredo you call `getResources()`? The object you are calling this on is null.

Comment: I do not use any of this call. I did not use getResources() but i think it's implecit call once u use `activity`

Comment: Post your activity code.

Comment: @OmarSilva i did

Comment: Where are you calling `updateTable` from? Make use this happens after the fragment is attached to an activity. For example, you cannot do `new TablePresentation().updateTable(temps)`

Comment: yes it's attached will update the question

Comment: so you've put `table!!.addView(row, i);` saying "hey I'm in control, table is DEFINITELY not null" - have you checked it isn't null? Also this :`view?.findViewById<View>(R.id.simpleTableLayout) as TableLayout` can be `view?.findViewById<TableLayout>(R.id.simpleTableLayout)`

Comment: but it does not even reach this line he bug on     ` val row =  TableRow(activity)`

Comment: That would have been helpful in original question.

Comment: sorry what is would have been  helpfull did not get u

Comment: So `activity` is null then - `TableRow` is calling `Context::getResources` on the `activity` instance which is null (`Activity` is a `Context`).

Comment: yes absolutly and now how to deal with

Comment: So if you knew all this, why not cut to the chase in your question?

Comment: i think if i call the methode inside `onViewCreated` i will not get all those troubles. But i have to use outside it

Comment: @MarkKeen i do not know why it's always null and what is make it like that and why once i use the methode out of onViewCreated i get the pb.I'm confused right now

Comment: you call this `val view = activity.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.table_fragment, parent, false)` - why aren't you using the `LayoutInflater` provided in `onCreateView` it should be : `val view = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.table_fragment, parent, false)` - also you can call `view?.context` for `TableRow(view?.context)` .. or something like this .. hard to pinpoint exact issue as several things need addressing ..

Comment: but how to reach this `view?.context` in ** updateTable**. Sorry if it's dump question but now Everything is blurry in my eyes. and in your previous comment do u want to me change  `val view = activity.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.table_fragment, parent, false)` to `val view = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.table_fragment, parent, false)` i have not really understood

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171117/discussion-between-zina-taklit-and-mark-keen).

Comment: erm, `view` (Java call `getView`) is a public method in  `DialogFragment` - consider add the layout to your xml, and just changing its visibility in your `DialogFragment` - much easier than trying to add a view dynamically.

Comment: How to do that i have no idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fragment is not attached.

You're doing this:

```
    TableSon= TableController(view.getTableChild())
    setChildSFather()
    TableSon?.updateTable( father!!.giveTemps())
```

Where `getTableChild` returns what has been initialized like this:

```
val tablePresentation=TablePresentation()
```

This creates an "rogue" Fragment that is not attached to anything.

One way to fix this particular issue would be to remember the array in the `TablePresentation` fragment and call `updateTable` from `onAttach`.

EDIT: By "remember" I mean save it into the arguments, not just store in a member.

Comment: please share an exaple of how cause i did not get u well. Then i have used the same logic before for the buttoms and i had absolutly no pb. I wonder

Comment: please especially  share how to use `onAttach`.

Comment: Well it seems complexe cause i'm trying to stimulate PAC architect which is outdated.

Comment: Again, I'm not sure how to fit an example in your architecture, I think there too many things behind the scenes. But in general in Android, you instantiate a Fragment, pass data into it via `fragment.setArguments()`. Then anything you do with views, you should do it after `onCreateView` was called (if you only need to access the context of your activity, you can do it in `onAttach`)

Comment: ok so how to access the context from on attatch. and i can not see the diff doing that from oncreate or onattach.U do me a pleasure if u expalin

Comment: in onAttach you're receiving a valid activity (which is a Context). So it would fix the issue with `getResources` on null reference. `onCreateView` could be a better place for inflating views. I'm not sure if you realize that there are two fragments here. In one you're working in lifecycle callbacks, but the other one is instantiated via `new` and then its methods are called directly.

Answer (score 0):

@Dennis K weel we can call the method from onAttach or even from onViewCreated.
I know that work perfectly.

But my question was why we can not do that **the call of the method i mean ** outside of those 2 methode.Why could not we do that?

Finally because i have not found the answer to my why i have called my methode from onViewCreated.or even on onAttached.like have u said @Dennis K.

Here is the call

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        table = view?.findViewById<View>(R.id.simpleTableLayout) as TableLayout
        updateTable()
    }
```

Here is the function

```
fun updateTable()
     {
         val temps=controller?.getTemps()
         for (i in 0 until temps!!.size) {
        val row =  TableRow( activity)
        row.setLayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
        row.setWeightSum(2.0f)
        val tv1 = TextView( activity)
        val tv2= TextView(activity)

        tv1.setLayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f))
        tv2.setLayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f))

        tv1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)
        tv2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)

        tv1.setText((i+1).toString())
        tv2.setText(temps.get(i).toString())

        // finally add our textviews to TableRow
        row.addView(tv1)
        row.addView(tv2)
        //finally add our TableRow to Tablelayout
        table!!.addView(row, i)
        }
     }
```

Why why why outside of onAttach/onViewCreated we can not   receive a valid activity (which is a Context).

Comment: We can. But not always. Fragments go through a lifecycle - i.e. at different times different actions are possible. Sometimes OS can kill a fragment to reclaim its resources. You need to use lifecycle callbacks to track in what state your fragment is, and organize your flow accordingly. See in more details here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments